# For a given integer N, find the greatest integer x where 2 to the power of x is less than or equal to N

Tags: python

I think I'm mostly just struggling to understand the question, and because of that my code is just all wrong. Any help at all would be appreciated, don't need to give me the full answer, just need to understand what the question wants me to do, if anyone can figure it out from my picture.

[link to pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j51QU.png)

The code I used for what I thought it was:

```
N = int(input())
a = 2
x = 2
while x < N:
    x = a**2
    if x > N:
      pass
    else:
      print(x, end = " ")
      a+=2
```

Comment: You can solve this directly with a log and a floor operation.

Answer (score 0):

"For a given integer N, find the greatest integer x where 2 to the power of x is less than or equal to N."

In clearer language, they want you to find the **largest power of 2** that is **less than or equal to N**.

Here is a very naive way to achieve this

```
N = int(input())

power = 0

while 2 ** power <= N:
    power += 1

power -= 1

print(power, 2 ** power)
```

We iteratively increase powers of 2 until we find one that is greater than `N`. However, there is a simpler way to achieve this. As @joanis mentioned, if we want to find the closest power of 2 we can use logarithms like this

```
import math

N = int(input())

power = int(math.log(N, 2))

print(power, 2 ** power)
```

Which simplifies our code. Also, the second part of the question tells you to print the exponent value and 2 raised to the power of that exponent, which you can see included in both code segments.